# Zend Translator ignores changes made in Bootstrap

Tags: zend-framework2, translation, gettext

I want to localize my application based on the user settings and if none is set fall back to the default one.

To archieve this, I wrote the following method which hooks into the Zend\Mvc\Application bootstrap hook:

```
$translator = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('translator');
$translator->setLocale(Locale::acceptFromHttp($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']));

$lang = 'en_US';

if(isset($lang)) {
    $translator->setLocale($customerSession->customerData->sprache);
}
```

My browser is configured to send de_DE.

When I try to get the translator in the controller and use it to translate a string everything works as expected.

But as soon as I try to use the translate helper in a view it falls back to the default configuration set in the configuration files from my module.

Any idea how to modify the Class the translate helper uses instead of the translator-service one?

FYI: the default configuration says italian for testing purposes.

**Edit:** 
I figured out that the view plugin manager creates the translate-object using a new instance of the translator-object with the basic configuration. Any idea how to make the changed translator-class global?

Answer (score 1):

Since 2.2.0 there’s a new MvcTranslator, but you don’t have to initialize it separately. Simply create an alias for it in your module.conf.php:

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'aliases' => array(
        'translator' => 'MvcTranslator',
    ),
),
```

See [ZendSkeletonApplication](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/commit/0253af3d697c22ef6bc1572cc8e040c020c8f70e).

Answer (score 0):

You need to also set the locale for the MvcTranslator:

```
$mvctranslator = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('MvcTranslator');
$mvctranslator->setLocale($locale);
```